# How to convert a float32 img to uint8 where range is(-1 to -0.85)?

Tags: python, scikit-image, python-imageio

I want to convert a `float32` image into `uint8` image in Python.
I tried using the following code, but the output image only has values like 2 and 3 so the image is practically black.

```
gen_samples[0] * 255).round().astype(np.uint8)
```

When I try displaying the `float32` image I get a blackish/greyish image where I can somewhat make out  the required image.

Comment: What does your data (`gen_samples`) look like? How is it stored?

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the array to 0..1 first.

Assuming `gen_samples` is the image matrix:

```
arr_min = np.min(gen_samples)
arr_max = np.max(gen_samples)
gen_samples = (gen_samples - arr_min) / (arr_max - arr_min)
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the values -1 or -0.85 will be in the image, so `np.min` and `np.max` doesn't necessarily work here

Comment: @QWERTYL I interpreted OP's message to say that the actual range already is -1 to -.85 - but sure, `arr_min` and `arr_max` could be hard-coded :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question using `scikit-image` you are probably using skimage. In this case [`img_as_ubyte`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html?highlight=image%20uint#img-as-ubyte) should do the trick:

```py
from skimage.util import image_as_ubyte

img = img_as_ubyte(gen_samples[0])
```

Further, since you tagged the question with `imageio-python` I'll assume that the image data actually comes from some (binary) image format rather than being generated in the script. In this case, you can often use the backend that does the decoding and do the conversion while the image is being loaded. This is, however, specific to the format being used, so for a more specific answer you would have to provide more insight into where your images are coming from.